# Java Oracle Example on Guarded Blocks

Tags: java, oracle, concurrency

**EDIT:** Ok, this is really stupid but I don't know why I didn't see it was a normal loop without the usual increments. I hope I was drunk when I posted this question because now I feel super idiot. Thanks anyway guys!

I'm following some tutorials on Java multi-threading in order to gather as much information and examples as possible.

On the Oracle website there is an official tutorial on Java Concurrency and I am looking at the Guarded Blocks section ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)).

Whereas all the concepts are clear, I am reading the Producer/Consumer example at the bottom of the page and I do not understand some parts of the code.

Specifically, in the following is the code for the run() method of the Consumer class, where I do not understand how that for loop is supposed to work. It doesn't even look as it can work to me.

Can anyone explain me?

```
public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (String message = drop.take();
             ! message.equals("DONE");
             message = drop.take()) {
            System.out.format("MESSAGE RECEIVED: %s%n", message);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just for loop being used in a non-idiomatic way.

You have the initialization `String message = drop.take();` (instead of `int i = 0;`).

Then you have the test `!message.equals("DONE");` (instead of `i < 10`).

Finally you have the "increment" or loop-advance or whatever the actual term is. Get the next value with `message = drop.take();` (instead of `i++`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier to understand when converted to a while-loop:

```
public void run() {
    Random random = new Random();

    String message = drop.take()
    while (!message.equals("DONE")) {
        System.out.format("MESSAGE RECEIVED: %s%n", message);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        message = drop.take()
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the for-loop generally consists of three parts:

```
for (INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; AFTERTHOUGHT) 
{
// Code for the for-loop's body goes here.
}
```

INITIALIZATION is run once before the first iteration, CONDITION is checked prior to every iteration and AFTERTHOUGHT is executed after every iteration.

(Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for-loops)

So in this example, the INITIALIZATION of the for-loop creates the *message* variable and takes the first message from *drop*. It then checks it in the CONDITION block to see if its is anything but *DONE*. If it is, the loop body is executed once, printing the message and sleeping for up to 5000 milliseconds. Then the next message is taken in the AFTERTHOUGHT clause and the loops checks the CONDITION block again to either print the next message or leave the loop once it receives *DONE*.